# Behavior for enabling/disabling a WPF ComboBox depending on number of items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, behavior

Whenever the ItemsSource of a WPF ComboBox changes (i.e. adding or removing elements, or assigning a new Collection), I want it to do the following (pseudo code):

```
IsEnabled = Items.Count > 1;

if (Items.Count == 1)
    SelectedItem = Items.First();
```

I'm using MVVM, and I know how to do it in MVVM. But I want to avoid the boilerplate code, and IMHO it is too UI-specific for the ViewModel to care about. So is there a way to specify this in a `Behavior<ComboBox>`?

I couldn't find a ComboBox event I could subscribe to. If possible, it should work on ObservableCollection as well as ICollectionView or List etc.

Comment: Could you handle Enabled/Disabled with a DataTrigger such as `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItemsInList}" Value="False">  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/ </DataTrigger>`

Comment: Why use a DataTrigger isntead of just binding IsEnabled directly to HasItemsInList? But that property is the boilerplate I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I suppose you could bind to it directly, however if you have multiple properties that can affect `IsEnabled` then triggers do a good job of handling that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with triggers:

```
<Style x:Key="customComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                     Value="1">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you for example put this in your `App.xaml` file, you can use it across the whole application, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" Style="{StaticResource customComboBox}" />
```

Comment: I changed it to also set Enabled to False when there is 1 element, but I think I'm going with this solution. It might not work for everyone, i.e. if you need different combinations of styles, but it's good enough for what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the change of the source collection from the change of `ItemsSource` DependencyProperty and the change of the source collection items from CollectionChanged events provided that the source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

public class ItemsControlBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ItemsControl));
        dpd?.AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnItemsSourceChanged);

        AddSourceCollection();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ItemsControl));
        dpd?.RemoveValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnItemsSourceChanged);

        RemoveSourceCollection();
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveSourceCollection();
        AddSourceCollection();
    }

    private INotifyCollectionChanged? _collection;

    private void AddSourceCollection()
    {
        _collection = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (_collection is not null)
        {
            _collection.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }
        Apply();
    }

    private void RemoveSourceCollection()
    {
        if (_collection is not null)
        {
            _collection.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }
        _collection = null;
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Apply();
    }

    private void Apply()
    {
        AssociatedObject.IsEnabled = _collection is ICollection { Count: > 1 };

        if (AssociatedObject is Selector selector)
        {
            selector.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, this solution relies on heavy reflection and in addition has a negative and unexpected impact on the observed object's lifetime. In this case the attaching element (the ComboBox). The static reference created by PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged will extend the lifetime to the lifetime of the application. As this behavior is unwanted, you have essentially created a memory leak. To avoid the leak the value changed event handler must be explicitly removed.

Comment: For example, when innocently removing the observed element from the visual tree you must explicitly detach the attached property/behavior in order to have PropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged to be called. Because this is not intuitive this solution is introducing a potential memory leak.

Comment: A significant improvement of your solution would involve handling the FrameworkElement.Unloaded event to unhook the property value changed callback and other handlers (i.e. call Behavior.Detach).

Comment: @BionicCode. Jeez, I wasn't aware of that. So OnDetaching is not called automatically when the element is removed from the visual tree? I'm not sure I trust the Unloaded event, since I had massive problems with Loaded on ListView items. WPF kept creating new instances when selecting another element.

Comment: @user2727133 No, Behavior.Detach is not called by the framework. Attach is also not called by the framework. It's invoked by the BehaviorCollection class when you add a Behavior<T> instance to the collection. When you remove the Behavior the collection will also implicitly invoke Detach. So either call Behavior.Detach explicitly or remove it from the BehaviorCollection.

Comment: @user2727133 Loaded and Unloaded events are always raised when a FrrameworkElement was added/removed from the visual tree (when the FrameworkElement is ready for the rendering process). In context of ListViewItems you must know that ListView uses UI virtualization. When it reuses containers (i.e. ListViewItem instances) of course the Loaded event is not raised, because the container is still valid. You can trust that Unloaded event too: it will be raised when the element is detached from the element tree.

Comment: @user2727133 The only caveats: it only must be loaded before and Loaded/Unloaded is also raised when switching the application theme. So while you can trust that the Unloaded event is raised as expected the event itself is not the safest trigger in order to unhook event handlers. There is still a chance for a memory leak.

Comment: @user2727133 But since there are better solutions you are not stuck. Simply don't subscribe to events where lifetime is crucial but you are not able to control it. PropertyDescriptor is not the way to go. You can use the behavior to add a Trigger dynamically or to attach a Binding to an internal binding source property on the behavior in order to get property change notifications.